# How to subtract checkbox values?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox

When I select a checkbox, the value gets added in the textbox and gets incremented when I check another. Problem is, when I uncheck them, it should subtract the values too. Total_sum in my textbox. Please help me.

```
Dim sum As Integer

Public Sub ChangeValue(add As Boolean, value As Decimal)
    sum += If(add, value, -value)
    Total_sum.Text = sum.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub chk_1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_1.CheckedChanged
    If chk_1.Checked = True Then
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked = True, 25I)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_2.CheckedChanged
    If chk_2.Checked = True Then
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 25I)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_3_1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_3_1.CheckedChanged
    If chk_3_1.Checked = True Then
        chk_3_2.Checked = False
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 15I)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_3_2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_3_2.CheckedChanged
    If chk_3_2.Checked = True Then
        chk_3_1.Checked = False
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 30I)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_4_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_4.CheckedChanged
    If chk_4.Checked = True Then
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 20D)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_5_1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_5_1.CheckedChanged
    If chk_5_1.Checked = True Then
        chk_5_2.Checked = False
        chk_5_3.Checked = False
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 0D)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chk_5_2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_5_2.CheckedChanged
    If chk_5_2.Checked = True Then
        chk_5_1.Checked = False
        chk_5_3.Checked = False
        ChangeValue(DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked, 15D)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Fredou I have used your code but still having a problem. can you help me?

Comment: You should have one method to do the calculation(s) and that method should use a set of data stored in member variables. In each of your event handlers, you should update the relevant field(s) and then call that method. Simple.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you. I will try as per your instructions.

Comment: You have your `Decimal` and `Integer` types intermixed. It looks like they are all Integer values so make `value` in the `ChangeValue` sub an `Integer`.

Comment: That because you call `ChangeValue`only when `Checked = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the DirectCast. You know what the sender is. Just passing the Boolean chk_1.Checked to ChangeValue will either increment or decrement the sum.

```
Private sum As Integer

Public Sub ChangeValue(add As Boolean, value As Integer)
    sum += If(add, value, -value)
    Total_sum.Text = sum.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub chk_1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk_1.CheckedChanged
    ChangeValue(chk_1.Checked, 25)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have change Decimal to Integer. have also change chk_1.Chaked for passing values but still it only increment the sum not decrement

Comment: Works for me. Did change the code to `ChangeValue(chk_1.Checked, 25)`

Comment: yes I change the code to ChangeValue(chk_1.Checked,25)

Comment: Forget the other check boxes temporarily and just try to get `chk_1` working. If necessary, start a new project and add one check box to a new form. Test my code to see if it will add and subtract.

Comment: @DhanashreeRangari You are very welcome. If I have answered your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.